# is it not possible to define two queries in a function of zend frame work controller

Tags: zend-framework

i am new to zend frame work need two mysql queries ca be define in a function of zend controller but it showing

error message as Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty

```
public function addisplayAction()
  {

    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();  
$DB = $registry['DB'];

   $sql = "SELECT cateno,catename,image FROM hl_category ORDER BY`hl_category`.`cateno` ASC LIMIT 0 , 42";
      $result = $DB->fetchAssoc($sql);
    $sql1 = mysql_query("select * from ad where cid=8");
   $result1 = $DB->fetchAssoc($sql1);
  $this->view->assign('title','Member List');
      $this->view->assign('description','Below, our members:');
       $this->view->assign('datas',$result);    
  $this->view->assign('datas1',$result1);
```

Comment: I'm curious which DB adapter you are using. ZF dosen't have a native Mysql adapter, just Mysqli and PDO_Mysql. So I assume you are setting up a MySql adapter in your bootstrap. Yhe code you have presented looks ok, different but ok. although I'm not sure mysql_query will work in this instance.

Comment: You are passing an SQL query string to the first fetchAssoc() call, but a MySQL result object to the second, which is probably the cause of your error. If you are using Zend_Db I'd recommend not using the mysql_* functions at all.

Comment: as  RockyFord specified without mysql_query executing the process thank you  RockyFord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG!!!! You are using Zend framework and put in your code mysql_query() ???? :D

You need to use the Zend_Db...

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.html